# Inject HttpService in an OSGi bundle in JBoss 7

Tags: osgi, jboss7.x

I have a JBoss 7.1.2 application server up and running and now I wanted to deploy a OSGi bundle in it which registers a servlet. (kind of Hello World, but via a servlet)

Probably it is possible to archive this via a WAB, but as in OSGi, I thought it should also work in a simple, non wab bundle.

I created a bundle with an Activator as follows:

```
snip..
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        ServiceReference<?> httpServiceReference = bundleContext.getServiceReference(HttpService.class.getName());
        System.out.println("ref: " + httpServiceReference);

        HttpService httpService = (HttpService) context.getService(httpServiceReference);
        System.out.println(httpService.getClass().getName());

        try {
            httpService.registerServlet("testservlet", new MyServlet() , null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

After deploying and starting the bundle, the httpServiceReference is `null`.
I think this is strange, because when I look at the felix web console, there actually **is** HtttpService available. (from pax-web)

Does anyone know why my reference could be null here?
Thanks!

Comment: could you go through this [tutorial](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-http-service.html). just add all necessary bundles to your jboss environment. hope it wokrs, but give me a feedback if not.

Comment: Actually, above code works nicely on the nightly JBoss 7.2.x.alpha.
The HttpService gets injected on that version, so to me it seems a bug in the 7.1.x series (tried both 7.1.1 and 7.1.2)

Comment: Theoretically it could also be a visibility problem. Is there more than one exporter of the package containing HttpService? If so, maybe your code gets wired to the "wrong one". Try using getAllServiceReferences() instead to see if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making the classical OSGi mistake. In the `start(BundleContext context)` method you are obtaining the reference to HttpService assuming its already started. The OSGi container starts bundles in some order. If your application bundle starts before the bundle that registers `HttpService` you will get a `null` reference. I suspect that's what is going on. You might be better off using `ServiceTracker` instead.

```
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {       
    ServiceTracker httpServiceTracker = new ServiceTracker(bundleContext, HttpService.class, new ServiceTrackerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public Object addingService(ServiceReference srf) {
            HttpService httpService = bundleContext.getService(srf);
              try {
                    httpService.registerServlet("testservlet", new MyServlet() , null, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void modifiedService(ServiceReference arg0, Object arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void removedService(ServiceReference arg0, Object arg1) {

        }

    });

    httpServiceTracker.open();
}
```